# $H\le G$ and $|H|=10$, $a^6\in H$, what could $|a|$ be? Without using Lagrange's theorem.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is exercise 43 in chapter 4 of Gallian's *Contemporary Abstract Algebra*, 9th edition:

> Suppose that $H$ is a subgroup of a group $G$ and $|H|=10$.  If $a$ belongs to $G$ and $a^6$ belongs to $H$, what are the possibilities for $|a|$?

The answer in the back of the book is "all divisors of 60".  It's easy to reach this conclusion using Lagrange's theorem: since $a^6\in H$, $|a^6|$ is a divisor of $|H|=10$, so $|a|$ is a divisor of $6\cdot 10 = 60$.  The problem is that Lagrange's theorem isn't proven until chapter 7.  Chapter 4 contains the special case of Lagrange's theorem when the ambient group is cyclic (Corollary 1 on p79: "In a finite cyclic group, the order of an element divides the order of the group"), but I don't see how to deduce this result using only that case, since neither $G$ nor $H$ is assumed cyclic.

Is there a way to do this exercise using only the facts introduced in the book up until this point?

Comment: You can try to argue by considering the homomorphism $x \to x^6$ of $\langle{a\rangle}\subset H$ to itself or by considering the coset space $G/H$, but both are really just roundabout ways of proving Lagrange's theorem. This is exactly the sort of question that theorem solves, so I'm not sure what the point of the exercise would be without it. (It also turns out that there are exactly two groups of order $10$, but I'm not sure how you would be expected to prove that without even Lagrange's theorem.)

Comment: Right.  And homomorphisms and cosets haven't been introduced at this point in the book either.  My best guess is that the author meant to assume in the exercise that $G$ or $H$ was cyclic, so that the special case of Lagrange's theorem that is mentioned in this chapter could be applied.

Comment: Since $a^6\in H$ we have $\{a^6, a^{12}, a^{18}, \cdots\}\in H$.  As $|H|=10$ This list must repeat.  Indeed $\{a^6, a^{12}, a^{18}, \cdots, a^{66}\}$ must contain a duplicate (or several duplicates).  But if $a^i=a^j$ with $i<j$ then $a^{i-j}=e$ so the order of $a$ would have to be a divisor of $i-j$.

Comment: Ought to have stressed:  the argument sketched in my last comment does not instantly get you to a full solution, though it does produce a convenient list of candidates for the order of $a$.  A priori, we might have the duplicates being, say, $a^{48}=a^{6}$ which would tell us that $a^{42}=e$...and that would allow $7$ as a possible order for $a^6$, which later results show is not possible.  Still, it greatly narrows the search.

Comment: @Lulu I'm trying to go about it your way but am having trouble with the logic. How do I know how many duplicates there are and which ones are duplicates? Let's say $a^{66}$ and naturally $a^6$ are duplicates. Clearly we get that $|a|$ divides $60$. But how to know how many other duplicates there could be and which ones?  And so what if I get $7$ as a possible order? I guess I don't see how that would be contradicted exactly instead of listed among possibilities since it could always be that $|a^6|=1$

Comment: @upanddownintegrate  It doesn't matter how many duplicates there are, nor which there are, the only thing that matters is that there *are* duplicates.  That we know because the alternative would be that the list was infinite, but it can't be since it sits inside a finite set.  Note my earlier comment however:  this method doesn't give a complete solution, it just narrows the search a lot.

Answer (score 4):

For every $h\in H$, $h^{10}=1$ (you do not need to know the full Lagrange theorem for this). Therefore $a^{60}=1$. So the order of $a$ divides $60$. Every divisor $d$ can occur. Indeed, let $C_{60}=\langle c\rangle$ be the cyclic group of order $60$. Then the subgroup $H$ generated by $c^6$ is of order $10$.Every $a\in C_{60}$ satisfies $a^6\in H$. For every divisor $d$ of $60$ the element $a=c^{60/d}$ has order $d$. So indeed every divisor of $60$ can occur as the order of your $a$.

**Update** The fact that in a group of order $n$ every element has order $\mid n$ is proved in the book only in Chapter 7. But here we need it just for $n=10$. Here is the proof. The order of $h\in H$ cannot be bigger than $10$. If it is not $1,2,5,10$ it must be $3, 4, 6, 7, 8$ or $9$. If it is $6,8, 9$ then $h^2$ or $h^3$ has order $3$ or $4$. So we can assume that the order of $h$ is $3,4$ or $7$. These cases are almost identical. Suppose that the order is $4$. So the different powers of $h$ are $1,h,h^2, h^3$. There is an element $u\in H\ne 1,h,h^2,h^3$. Then the $8$ elements $1,h,h^2,h^3, u, uh, uh^2, uh^3$ are all different. Let $v\in H$ be an element not in this set. Then the eleven elements $1,h,h^2,h^3, u, uh, uh^2, uh^3, v, vh, vh^2$ are all different, and all in $H$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=a^6, |x|=k, x\in H$. If $k>10,$ then $|x|=k>10=|H|$, which is impossible. So $k\le 10$.

To show $k|10$, we need to exclude those cases: $k\ne3,4,6,7,8,9$. We group them into two cases, (1) $k\ne 6,7,8,9$, (2) $k\ne3,4$

For case.(1), we use $k=7$ as an example, let $H$ be

$$H=\{e, x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5, x^6,a, b,c\}$$

and define $C_1=\{e, x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5, x^6\}$. Surely, $a\notin C_1$.

Since $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, it is closed under multiplication, hence,
$$a,ax,ax^2,ax^3,ax^4,ax^5,ax^6\in H$$

First, we can show $ax^i\ne x^j$, otherwise, $a=x^{j-i}\in C_1$, contradiction.

$H$ contains 10 elements, which means at least two of $a,ax,ax^2,ax^3,ax^4,ax^5,ax^6$ must be idential, hence

$$ax^i=ax^j\Rightarrow a=x^{j-i}\in C_1$$

Contradiction.

For other subcases in case.(1) $k\ne 6,7,8,9$ can be shown in the same way.

For case.(2), we use $k=3$ as an example, let $H$ be

$$H=\{e, x, x^2,a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5, a_6, a_7\}$$

and define $C_2=\{e, x, x^2\}$. Surely, $a_m\notin C_2, m=1,2,\dots,7$.

First, we have $$a_1,a_1x,a_1x^2\in H$$ by similar way as used in case.(1), we can show

$$x^i\neq a_1 x^j,~(0\le i<j\le 2)~~ \cap~~a_1x^p\neq a_1 x^q,~(0\le p<q\le 2)$$

without loss of generality, we assign them as

$$a_1=a_1, ~~~~a_2=a_1x, ~~~~a_3=a_1x^2$$

then we update $H$ as

$$H=\{e, x, x^2,a_1, a_1x, a_1x^2, a_4, a_5, a_6, a_7\}$$

since $a_4\notin \{e, x, x^2,a_1, a_1x, a_1x^2\}$, we use the same construction $a_4, a_4x, a_4x^2$ and show

$$x^i\neq a_4 x^j,~~~ \cap~~~a_1x^p\neq a_4 x^q,~~~ \cap~~~a_4x^\alpha\neq a_4 x^\beta~(0\le \alpha<\beta\le 2)$$

without loss of generality, we assign them as

$$a_4=a_4, ~~~~a_5=a_4x, ~~~~a_6=a_4x^2$$

again, we update $H$ as

$$H=\{e, x, x^2,a_1, a_1x, a_1x^2, a_4, a_4x, a_4x^2, a_7\}$$

Now by the similar construction, we can get $a_7, a_7x, a_7x^2$ which satisfy

$$x^i\neq a_7 x^j,~ \cap~a_1x^p\neq a_7 x^q,~ \cap~a_4x^\alpha\neq a_7 x^\beta~ \cap~a_7x^t\neq a_7 x^s~(0\le t<s\le 2)$$

So we get $12$ distinct elements and they are all in $H$, but $|H|=10$, contradiction.

By the same method, you can show $k\neq 4$ in case.(2), hence complete the proof.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could try proving Lagrange's Theorem for this simpler case.

Consider $b=a^6\in H$ and the subgroup $S=\{b,...,b^{|b|}\}\leq H$.

If we have $g\in h_1S\cap h_2S$ then, $g=h_1b^i=h_2b^j\Rightarrow h_1=h_2b^{j-i}$. But $h_1S=h_1\{b,...,b^{|b|}\}=$ $h_2b^{j-i}\{b,...,b^{|b|}\}=$ $h_2 \{b,...,b^{|b|}\}=h_2S$, because multiplying by $h^{j-i}$ only alters the order of elements. So these sets are equal if they have an intersection. The union of such sets when we vary $h$ yields all elements of $H$ (indeed $h\in hS $), so $H=\dot{\cup}_{h_i} h_iS$ and $|H|=\sum_{h_i} |h_i S|=\sum_{h_i}|S|=|S|d$. So $|S|=|b|$ divides $|H|=10$ and:

$$|S|=|b|=|a^6|=\left.\frac{|a|}{gcd(|a|,6)}\right|10$$

This means $|a|=2^{i_2}\cdot 3^{i_3}\cdot 5^{i_5} $ where $i_2\in \{0,1,2\}$,  $i_3\in\{0,1\}$ and $i_5\in\{0,1\}$.